# How to authenticate a user from LDAP based on mail and by uid with spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, ldap

I want a user to be able to login both by his uid and by mail ? How to achieve this using my spring Security configuration ?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().passwordParameter("password");
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        LdapContextSource contextSource;

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                    .ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDnPatterns("uid={0}")
                    .contextSource(contextSource);
        }
    }
}
```

At userDnPatterns can I specify another attribute along with uid? Or authentication with uid is standard ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a custom user search filter. The following code uses an OR filter that tries to match the uid or mail to the value entered by the user in the login screen:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().passwordParameter("password");
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        LdapContextSource contextSource;

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                    .ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDnPatterns("uid={0}")
                    .userSearchFilter("(|(uid={0})(mail={0}))")
                    .contextSource(contextSource);
        }
    }
}
```